# Can't find JQuery Selector :editable

Tags: jquery

I found a code example using ":editable" selector, but don't see it in JQuery API (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). What is the meaning of this selector?

Comment: Where did you find the code example? Or how did it look like?

Comment: Just from this very short context - I would assume it's a filter for _editable_ elements.

Comment: Could also be for elements like `contenteditable="true"` .. but without an example I can't say more

Comment: Any plugins involved with your example?

Comment: you can create custom `:*` selectors with jQuery, I'm sure the example you saw was using such a custom selector.

Answer (score 1):

This is the work of the [jQuery Editable](http://plugins.jquery.com/editable/) plugin.

The plugin doesn't even define `:editable` as a fully-fledged filter (i.e., [by using `$.expr[':'].editable`](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1055-creating-a-custom-filter-selector-with-jquery/)). It just [overwrites `.is`](https://github.com/victorjonsson/jquery-editable/blob/master/jquery.editable.js#L360) to handle the exact string "`:editable`":

```
$.fn.is = function(statement) {
        if( typeof statement == 'string' && statement.indexOf(':') === 0) {
            if( statement == ':editable' ) {
                return this.attr(EVENT_ATTR) !== undefined;
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the plugin you mean is jQuery Editable ([link](http://plugins.jquery.com/editable/)). It uses code like that:

```
if( $elem.is(':editable') ) {
    // It's editable, lets do stuff...
}
```

Which introduces the `:editable` selector. Code-Examples: [here](http://victorjonsson.se/168/jquery-editable?from=jQuery), see "Other code examples"